# How to set/remove insets in JavaFX TitledPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I've created a TitledPane in JavaFX with a single child component (a button) as follows:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <TitledPane animated="false" layoutX="137.0" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="untitled" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" >
                    <children >
                        <Button layoutX="193.1875" layoutY="133.5" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="374.0" prefWidth="598.0" text="Button" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </content>
        </TitledPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This appears as below. There is quite a bit a spacing around the button, I'd like to reduce this to either 0 or maybe, a single pixel. I don't see any property of either the AnchorPane or the TitledPane that will do this. Is there such a property?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to figure out issues like this.

The AnchorPane inside the TitledPane has padding of 0.8em (10px) on all sides. This is defined in the default stylesheet, modena.css. You can reset it in the FXML:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <content>
                <AnchorPane >
                <padding>
                        <Insets top="0" right="0" left="0" bottom="0"/>                 
                </padding>
                    <children >
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
            </content>
        </TitledPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

or with an external style sheet with

```
.titled-pane > * > * > AnchorPane {
    -fx-padding: 0em ;
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion on scenic view

Comment: @James_D: I've tried this but for some reason the CSS solution does not work. I've made a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607725/remove-insets-in-javafx-titledpane-with-css-not-working

Comment: This behaves so strangely. 0 is already the default padding value, however, you need to explicitly put the 0 padding into the FXML. Specifying 0 padding in SceneBuilder will not put them into the FXML, and then there will be padding.

Answer (score 6):

I already [answered on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607725/remove-insets-in-javafx-titledpane-with-css-not-working/45161258#45161258), but I also want to post it here, since it also perfectly matches this question.

To extend @James_D's answer:

If you do not use `AnchorPane` as the `TitledPane`'s content, but some other node, you have to adjust the CSS accordingly.

A universal CSS solution for removing padding on a `TitledPane`'s content, no matter which type of `Node` is used as content, is the following:

```
.titled-pane > .content > * {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}
```

This sets the padding for any child of the `TitledPane`'s content to `0px`.