# Remove insets in JavaFX TitledPane with CSS not working

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Based on a solution of James_D ([How to set/remove insets in JavaFX TitledPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065096/how-to-set-remove-insets-in-javafx-titledpane)) that I've tried, it seems that removing insets from a JavaFX TitledPane through CSS does not work? It does update correctly in Scene Builder, but at runtime the insets remain unchanged. Even Scenic View 8.0 reports a padding of 9.6.

**FXML example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" stylesheets="@newCascadeStyleSheet.css" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="test3.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
      <Accordion layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="270.0" prefWidth="320.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <panes>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                          <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="9.600000381469727" layoutY="9.600000381469727" prefHeight="124.0" prefWidth="318.0" text="Click Me!" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
              </TitledPane>
              <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
          <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled 3">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </TitledPane>
        </panes>
      </Accordion>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**CSS:**

```
.titled-pane {
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(0,100,157);
}
.titled-pane:focused {
    -fx-color: -fx-base;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(0,100,157);
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
titled-pane > .title  > .label{
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(0,100,157);
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
.titled-pane:focused > .title {
    -fx-color: rgb(0,100,157); 
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
.titled-pane > .title:hover {
    -fx-color: lightgrey;
}
.titled-pane > * > * > AnchorPane {
    -fx-padding: 0px ;
}
```

**View in Scene Builder: (Preview)**

[image: preview in scene builder]

**View at runtime:**

[image: view at runtime]

So it seems that the padding is not applied for some reason. In my main application I use a lot of `Accordion` containers. The other option was to add the padding in FXML code to the `AnchorPane` of the `TitledPane`, this works but is a time consuming job. Am I missing something in the CSS?

Comment: You need `.titled-pane > * > * >  #AnchorPane` for the selector, I think. Not sure why it is appearing to work in SceneBuilder though. Are you certain the css is being loaded at runtime?

Comment: Hi James_D, I've tried this but it has the same result.

Comment: I've updated the example with some more CSS elements. As you can see the CSS loads fine.

Comment: Can you try .titled-pane .content and set the padding to 0?

Comment: Nice suggestion, just tried that but gives the same result.

Comment: Another suggestion: .titled-pane .content AnchorPane and padding to 0.

Comment: Jep that seems to do the trick :) `.titled-pane .content AnchorPane {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}`. Can you add it as an answer so I can reward you the points?

Comment: Well, great it helped you, but honestly, for me it doesnt even make that much sense. We are going to set the padding for the AnchorPane to 0, but why isnt .content not enough? I would expect that all children inside the AnchorPane are now with padding 0, not the content of the TitledPane. I only suggested it because I had exactly the same issue in my own project.

Comment: Yea it does seem to behave strange. Setting the padding to 0 on .content did actually set the padding to zero except for the AnchorPane...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set/remove insets in JavaFX TitledPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065096/how-to-set-remove-insets-in-javafx-titledpane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `-fx-padding` to 0 on the following style classes.

```
.titled-pane .content AnchorPane {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend @NDY's answer:

If you do not use `AnchorPane` as the `TitledPane`'s content, but some other node, you have to adjust the CSS accordingly.

An universal CSS solution for removing padding on a `TitledPane`'s content, no matter which type of `Node` is used as content, is the following:

```
.titled-pane > .content > * {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}
```

This sets the padding for any child of the `TitledPane`'s content to `0px`.